# Find the probability that when a fair coin is flipped five times tails comes up exactly three times

Tags: probability, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Find the probability that when a fair coin is flipped five
times tails comes up exactly three times, the first and last
flips come up tails, or the second and fourth flips come
up heads.

Here the answer of first portion of the question (a fair coin is flipped five
times tails comes up exactly three times) is 5/16(not the required answer). I think this is a problem of inclusion and exclusion but i don't know how to proceed. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{5}{16}={5\choose2}\left(\frac12\right)^2\left(\frac12\right)^{5-2}$$

Comment: it is only the answer of "a fair coin is flipped five
times tails comes up exactly three times" portion

Comment: Yes it is, and? Note first, that you did not say you were able to answer this part, second, that it is explicitely recommended to avoid asking several questions in the same post, third, that the other question(s) you ask is (are) ambiguous, and fourth, that you provide no personal input about it (them).

Comment: Is this all one single question or are all of these smaller questions written in the same sentence?  Letting $A$ be the event that exactly three tails occur, $B$ be the event that first and last are tails, and $C$ the event that the second and fourth are heads, are you asking individually for each of $Pr(A),Pr(B),Pr(C)$?  Or are you asking for $Pr(A\cup B\cup C)$?

Comment: If you really are asking for $Pr(A\cup B\cup C)$ then you are correct that it is an inclusion-exclusion principle question.  How do you simplify writing $Pr(A\cup B\cup C)$ in terms of a summation of probabilities of events or intersections of events?  What probabilities in the summation do you know how to calculate?  What probabilities in the summation don't you know how to calculate?

Comment: yeah @JMoravitz i was asking for Pr(AUBUC), can you explain the procedure in answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

Inclusion-exclusion principle states that in the case of three events one has:

$$Pr(A\cup B\cup C)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(A\cap B)-Pr(A\cap C)-Pr(B\cap C)+Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$$

Let $A$ represent the event that exactly three of the flips are tails, $B$ the event that the first and last flips are both tails, and $C$ the event that the second and fourth flips are both heads.

For each of the above probabilities they can be calculated using standard counting techniques and multiplication principle by noting that the sample space of all sequences of coin flips is in fact equiprobable.

(*if the coin was biased and not fair, then a more direct probability argument should be used, but the basis of the argument is the same*)

For example, $Pr(A\cap B)$ refers to the probability of having exactly three tails and of those tails one is the first flip and another is the last flip.

$$T\underbrace{\underline{~~}\underline{~~}\underline{~~}}_{\text{1xT, 2xH}}T$$

There are only three ways in which you can satisfy having exactly three tails with first and last flip being tails, namely the sequences $TTHHT,~THTHT,~THHTT$

Since there are three valid sequences out of the $2^5=32$ equally likely sequences, we have $Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{3}{32}$

The remaining terms can be calculated similarly.